# is .submit() losing the name of the input of type submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I was wondering, I have a 2 input submit on my form.
One has a name :

```
<input name="_close" type="submit" id="myId" value="close">
```

And when I click on it, i submit the form via (after doing things in JS)

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Then in my server code I test on the `Request` if it has the `query` "_close" but it does not seem to be the case.

My question is : 
**Is there a way to make the `jQuery` method `.submit()` preserve the name of the input button clicked or to manually specify to the `.submit()` function the extra parameter I want in my next Request ?**

Thanks.

Comment: .submit() triggers the form to be submitted. All set values are sent, so should the submit value. I would recommend preventing underscores on the begin of the input name. '_language' and many others are preserved by some browsers and may cause this behaviour.

Comment: @rsplak I've changed the name, removing the "_" but it has no effect.

Comment: @Tristan I have updated my answer to explain why specifically it does not work as you expect and given you a couple of solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, i've added an hidden input cause i needed to be on the submit listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure about submit buttons and how /if they are passed across however if they are not you could in your pre submit javascript assign the value to a hidden input of the same name.

Ive just run an example for you.

**test.html**

```
<form action="test.php" action="POST" >
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Click me to submit" />
</form>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['submitButton'];
?>
```

This does echo **Click me to submit**

I then did another test using the submit function in jquery which does not pass the value over.

The reason is so that you can test server side which submit button was pressed since you may have more than one submit button on the form.  Checking the value allows you to test which one it was specifically that was used to submit the form.

To allow you to use an external input as a particular submit button so that its name/value pair is passed in the request instead of calling `submit()` on the form in your jquery, select the submit button itself and call `click()` on it.  This will tell the form that that particular submit button was used and therefore set its value in the request.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
$('#myForm').submit()
```

try

```
$('#myId').click();
```

This will make your form submission at the same time you can identify which button triggered form submit.